# Finding subfields of degree $3$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be the splitting ﬁeld of the polynomial $X^3−5$ over $Q$. Let $G = Gal(F/Q)$.

(i) Determine $G$ up to isomorphism.

(ii) Find all subﬁelds $M$ of $F$ such that $Q⊆M$ and $[M :Q] = 3$. [Give the answers in the form $Q(u)$ or $Q(u,v)$ for appropriate $u,v∈F$.]

[You may use the fact that $[F :Q] = 6$ without proof.]

---

Roots are: $5^{1/3}$, $5^{1/3}e^{\frac{2\pi}3i}$, $5^{1/3}e^{\frac{4\pi}3i}$.

Let $\xi=e^{\frac{2\pi}3i}$.
So splitting field $F=Q(5^{1/3}, 5^{1/3}\xi, 5^{1/3}\xi^2)=Q(5^{1/3}, \xi)$

I think (i) is $S_3$.

Stuck on (ii): I think we can have $M_1=Q(5^{1/3})$, $M_2=Q(5^{1/3}e^{\frac{2\pi}3i})$, $M_3=Q(5^{1/3}e^{\frac{4\pi}3i})$ will all have degree $3$. But i feel there are more.

Please help.

Comment: $\xi \eta = 1$ so $M_4 = M_1$

Comment: @Ted Oh yeah thanks. Is what i wrote all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $ [F : \mathbb{Q}] = 6 $, we know that the Galois group has order 6. On the other hand, each automorphism is uniquely determined by its values at $ \zeta_3 $ and $ \sqrt[3]{5} $, which have 2 and 3 $\mathbb{Q} $-conjugates, respectively. This means that the Galois group is generated by the automorphisms $ \sigma : \zeta_3 \to \zeta_3^2 $ and $ \tau : \sqrt[3]{5} \to \zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{5} $, and has presentation

$$ G = \langle \textrm{ord}(\sigma) = 2, \textrm{ord}(\tau) = 3, \sigma \tau \sigma = \tau^{-1} \rangle $$

from which we conclude that $ G \cong D_6 $.

The Galois correspondence links subfields of degree 3 with subgroups of $ D_6 $ with index 3, or order 2. To identify these subgroups, it suffices to identify all elements of order 2 in $ D_6 $. These elements are $ \{ \sigma, \sigma \tau, \sigma \tau^2 \} $, and the corresponding fixed fields are $ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{5}), \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3 \sqrt[3]{5}), \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3^2 \sqrt[3]{5}) $.

Comment: Is D_6 isomorphic to S_3?

Comment: Yes, they are the same group.

Comment: what is $\zeta_3$ in your answer?

Comment: A third primitive root of unity.

Comment: $e^{\frac{2 \pi}3i}$?

Comment: Yes, that is another representation.

Comment: So what I got for the subfields should be correct shouldn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40458/discussion-between-starfall-and-cooldudeman).

Answer (score 1):

If the answer to (i) is $S_3$ (it is...), then subfields of $F$ of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ correspond to subgroups of $S_3$ of index $3$, which means order $2$. Each such subfield is the fixed field of one of those subgroups. Can you take it from here?